# Zsh equivalent of bash's `expr index "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" xyzd`

Tags: zsh, string

What would be Zsh equivalent of bash's

```
expr index "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" xyzd
```

I am trying to find index of substring.

Comment: expr isn't a builtin. Why not use the exact same syntax?

Comment: The `expr` utility doesn't have an `index` operation. Or are you using GNU `expr` maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for a `zsh` builtin alternative to that non-standard `expr` usage (nothing to do with `bash` btw), you could do:

```
$ a=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz b=xyzd
$ echo ${a[(i)[$b]]}
4
```

With `i`, you get the index of the *first* match (or one plus the length of the haystack if there's no match). With `I` instead, you get the last match (or 0 if there's no match).

With any POSIX-like shell (including `bash` and `zsh`)

```
$ s=${a%%[$b]*}
$ echo "$(($#s + 1))"
4
```

Answer (score 3):

The implementation of `expr` found in the GNU coreutils package is an external utility and can be used in the same way regardless of what shell you are using.

In `zsh`,

```
expr index "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" xyzd
```

would return `4`, just as in `bash` or any other shell.

The `index` operation in GNU's `expr` is an extension to [the standard `expr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html), which means you'd likely to get an `expr: syntax error` error on systems without that particular implementation of `expr`.  This is regardless of what shell you use.

Comment: `index` is not a GNU extension. SysIII `expr` in 1980 had it. It's true it's not standard and not supported everywhere.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks. You're better at the history than I am. Slight modification to the answer...

Comment: Technically, `expr index "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" xyzd` would return a different result in the `rc` shell or derivatives as `"` is not a special quoting character in the syntax of those shells.

Comment: @Kusalananda `expr: syntax error` is exactly what I am getting.

Comment: @fg78nc That means that your `expr` is not GNU coreutils' `expr`.  Either install GNU coreutils on your Unix (the command might then be called `gexpr` rather than `expr`) or find an alternative way of performing the operation.

Comment: @Kusalananda, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

> `expr index "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" xyzd`
>
> I am trying to find index of substring.

Index of a substring, or of a character? `expr index` looks for any of the characters given in the second set, i.e. the above finds the position of the first `d`, not the substring `xyzd` (which doesn't exist in your string).

To look for the position of a substring, you could do, in standard shell:

```
haystack=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
needle=jkl
x=${haystack%%$needle*};
```

Now `x` contains the part of string before that substring, so `"${#x}"` is the zero-based position of `jkl` (`9`, in this case).

To look for the position of a character (byte) from a set of characters, you could similarly use:

```
haystack=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
needle=xqe;
x=${haystack%%[$needle]*};
```

Here, `"${#x}"` is 4. The downside of both of these is that if the string/character being searched for isn't found, `x` contains the whole of `haystack`, so you need to compare `"${#x}"` against the full length of `haystack` (not zero) to see if a match was found:

```
haystack=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
needle=qqq
x=${haystack%%$needle*}
if [ "${#x}" = "${#haystack}" ]; then echo "$needle not found"; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

As Kusalananda already pointed out in his comment, you can of course use `expr` in zsh too, but I guess you meant whether Zsh has a **builtin** way to do it.

The answer is "no", but it contains something similar:

```
v="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
i=${(SB)v#cdef}
```

This would set `i` to 3. However, there are two reasons why this doesn't work exactly the same as `expr index`:

In the example you gave, you are searching for *xyzd*, which is not present in your string, but since your string ends in *xyz*, `expr` gracefully drops the 'd' and returns a match. One might argue that the behaviour of Zsh is more reasonable in this respect, but of course if this an important issue for you, I would stick with Zsh.

The other reason why Zsh is different, is that `${(SB)v#...}` returns 1 if the string does **not** match. For example,

```
echo ${(SB)v#a}
echo ${(SB)v#7}
```

would both return 1. With this alone, you can't distinguish between a non-match and a match at the first character. One possible solution is to have it calculate the position and the length of the match:

```
# N returns the length of the match
index_and_length=${(SBN)v#...}
# index_and_length contains the index, a space, and the length
if [[ ${index_and_length#* } == 0 ]]
then
  echo no match
else
  index=${index_and_length% *}
  echo match at index $index
fi
```

UDPATE: As the comments to this post reveal, I misunderstood the purpose of `expr index`; hence, my answer, as given, is inadequate. However we can adapt it, because the "string" to be searched for, is a glob-pattern. Hence, square brackets will do the job:

```
# Search for the first occurance of one of the letters x y z d
index_and_length=${(SBN)v#[xyzd]}
```

Comment: The user's command would return the index of the first character found from the second string in the first. The d is the first one found, and it's at position 4 in the first string. That's how I think it works anyway. Or it's the index of the d in the second string... I don't have the manual here atm.

Comment: It looks for single characters: "index _STRING_ _CHARS_: index in _STRING_ where any _CHARS_ is found, or 0" -- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/expr.1.html

Comment: @Kusalananda : Thank you for pointing this out. I amended my answer to fit this interpretation.